# laravel lumen Input class not found

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Hi im testing lumen new laravel micro-frameword and when i'm trying to get input from a web service im getting this error

```
Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Input' not found in   C:\wamp\www\lumen\app\Http\Controllers\WsController.php
```

here is my code :

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class WsController extends Controller {

 public function addUser()
  {
        $user = new Models\User;
        $user->email = Input::get('email');;
        $user->password = strtoupper(md5(Input::get('password')));
        $user->first_name = Input::get('first_name');
        $user->last_name = Input::get('last_name');
        if($user->save()){
            return Models\User::all();
        }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Did you uncomment `withFacades` in `bootstrap.php`?

Comment: Can you give it a try just after your namespace, use App\Http\Controllers\Input;

Answer (score 7):

## Solution #1

Uncomment `$app->withFacades();` in `bootstrap/app.php` to allow you to use the Facade in your controller.

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Input;

class WsController extends Controller 
{

    public function addUser(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new Models\User;
        $user->email = Input::get('email');
        $user->password = strtoupper(md5(Input::get('password')));
        $user->first_name = Input::get('first_name');
        $user->last_name = Input::get('last_name');
        if($user->save()) {
            return Models\User::all();
        }
    }
}
```

## Solution #2 (personal preference)

Use dependency injection to inject the `Illuminate\Http\Request` class into your methods.

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class WsController extends Controller 
{

    public function addUser(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new Models\User;
        $user->email = $request->input('email');;
        $user->password = strtoupper(md5($request->input('password')));
        $user->first_name = $request->input('first_name');
        $user->last_name = $request->input('last_name');

        if($user->save()) {
            return Models\User::all();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How to add `$request` in a `GET` method?

Comment: @N.B. So either I create instance of `Request` object as argument or call statically by calling `Request` Facade?

Comment: @Volatil3 You can just pass an instance of `Request` to your model that you get as the first argument to your controller.

Comment: Difference between `Input` facade vs `$request->input()` is that you are accessing array on the later example you can not call methods like `has()`, `get()` etc

Answer (score -1):

```
   <?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request as Request;

    class WsController extends Controller {

    public function addUser()
    {        
            //creating a new user object from User model class
            $user = new Models\User;
            //getting the email value from the email input like Input::get('email');
            $user->email = Request::input('email');
            //same as above happen with the rest of the lines
            $user->password = strtoupper(md5(Request::input('password')));
            $user->first_name = Request::input('first_name');
            $user->last_name = Request::input('last_name');
            //User model has a save() method, so is calling if return true the if block will be executed
            if($user->save()){
            return Models\User::all();
            }
      }

            //this is the best way in lumen to execute some method, because lumen is powerful in small APIs and restful services
    }
```